# DropDownList error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my drpdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DriverGender" runat="server">
                         <asp:ListItem Text="M" Value="M"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="F" Value="F"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And from the code behind i would like to select a value from the dropdown depending on the value stored in the database. 
Code:

```
DriverGender.Items.FindByValue((String)DataReaderObj["gender"]).Selected = true;
```

But this is the recurring error i get :
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Is the DriverGender control inside a repeater or grid view?

Comment: Which event in the code behind is executing that code?  (Asking in case that DriverGender has been instantiated.)  Also, are the values coming from the database capitalized?

Comment: Perhaps there are leading or trailing spaces in the value coming from the database.

Comment: @ Michael Liu :yes there was some trailing spaces used the trim() method to remove them and now the right value is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one of three things, and I'm betting it's number 2.

1. `DriverGender` or its `Items` collection is null.
2. There is no item in `DriverGender` with a `Value` equal to the value of `DataReaderObj["gender"]`.
3. `DataReaderObj` is null.

So for number 2 for example, you would need an item contained in `DriverGender` that has a `Value` (not `Text`) exactly equal to whatever text value is represented by `DataReaderObj["gender"]`.

Comment: Yes, but is that value *in* the list of values of `DriverGender` at the time of executing that line of code? *Are you sure?* You need to just debug the code and step through to make sure.

Comment: I used a a label to display the value from the database and it did display the right answer

Comment: That doesn't mean that it is contained within `DriverGender`. Again, step through and check the `Items` collection right before that line is executed and make sure an item with that `Value` property exists.

Comment: Thank u Justin .i debugged and found out that the value pulled from the database was "M    "(ie M with some space) hence it did not get the output .

Comment: It is funny how a programmer insist on telling "getting correct value from the database" while actually it was not the correct value("M " instead of "M") there are answers that told you this, and none of them are accepted as answer and one of them did not even get up vote. Do you think people should just help you and you cant even give an up vote or mark as correct answer...

Comment: @Numenor: I have accepted Justin 's answer , Im sorry that i took  time to mark the correct answer .Will not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

check out the value of `(String)DataReaderObj["gender"]` perhaps its null(empty string) or a string that does not match to "M" or "F"

Comment: i did check that and that returns the correct value from the database

Answer (score 0):

```
DriverGender.Items.FindByValue((String)DataReaderObj["gender"].trim()).Selected = true;
```